# VueJS - How to have a vertical line just before the boxes for naming purpose using HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, vue.js, box

I want a vertical line just before the boxes in order to name those boxes in the y axis.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="rows" v-if="this.system == 'cpu'">
          <div class="columns is-mobile">
            <div class="column  is-2">box a</div>
            ...
          </div>

          <div class="columns is-mobile">
            <div class="column is-2">box b</div>
            ...
          </div>
```

Here is my output:

[image]

As you can see my picture, i want to have a vertical line with text on it, so please let me know how it can be done in my scenario.

I am looking for the vertical line in the left of the boxes in order to name it. Where the line must cover both the boxes in order to name the 2 boxes.

Comment: can you paste an image about you want to do?

Comment: Vertical line where? left? right? middle? per textbox? maybe not? the question is very unclear

Comment: Just before the boxes, that is in the left, i want to add a vertical line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could apply a [`border-left`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-left) style to the `.rows` container:

```css
.rows {
  border-left: solid 1px red;
}
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/gOmYBvV)